# Proof that two norms $\lVert\cdot\rVert_1$ and $\lVert\cdot\rVert_2$ are equivalent

Tags: normed-spaces

> 1. Two norms $\def\norm#1{\lVert#1\rVert}\norm\cdot_1$ and $\norm\cdot_2$ are **equivalent** iff  $\;\exists\;c_1,c_2>0$ such that $c_1\norm x_1\le \norm x_2\le c_2\norm x_1$

Show that $\norm x_1=\sum_{i=1}^n \lvert x_i \rvert$ and $\norm x_2=\left ( \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 \right )^{1/2}$ are equivalent.

It looks like $c_2$ is $1$, and that this can be proven with induction. But what could $c_1$ be?

*edit*

I mean what I don't understand is the following: If I square both terms, and expand $(\sum_{i=1}^n \lvert x_i \rvert)^2 = \left ( \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 \right ) + \sum_{i=1}^n x_i(x_k+\dotsb+x_n)_{x_k\neq x_i}$. However, the second term grows with $n$, so how can $\frac{\norm x_1}{\norm x_2} \leq C$ at all?

Comment: Well, I think that $n$ is kept *fixed*.

Comment: Note: this is a specific case of the theorem that all norms on a finite dimensional vector space are equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to show that for a fixed $n$ the norms $\|\|_1,\|\|_2$ are equivalent in $\mathbb R^n$. The constant $c_1$ will depend on $n$.

Hint:
[Cauchy Schwarz inequality.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality)

Answer (score -1):

Let $x=x_i$ for all $i$.  Then $||x||_1=x\dim x$, and $||x||_2=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{\dim x}x^2}=\sqrt{x^2\dim x}=x\sqrt{\dim x}$.  Therefore $$ \lim_{\dim x\to\infty} \frac{||x||_1}{||x||_2}=\sqrt{\dim x}=\infty $$
So the two cannot be equivalent by your definition.